# sql server for replication and web application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I have a push subscriber in transactional replication (and the distributer is the publisher), in this subscriber I configured sql server port on 1433, 
and I have a web application which connect to this subscriber database, and I want to use any port but not 1433,
Can I configure SQL server to listen to two different ports one will be used in replication (which stay 1433) , and the other for web request, and how to do that ??

In case of a single port, If the default port of sql server(1433) is changed this will affect on replication cause subscriber and publisher listening on the same port, is this right ??